# How can I insert a greek letter in Dia diagram software?

Tags: diagram, dia

I need to insert a greek letter in a diagram. Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: Have you looked in the [character map](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CharacterMap) tool ? You should be able to find the character you need there, and then you can copy / paste it into your diagram.

Comment: @JonasCz Yes but It doesn't paste in Dia nor in GIMP.

Comment: Have you tried using the Ctrl + V shortcut to paste ? That usually works everywhere.

Comment: @JonasCz Yes, my usual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the character you need in the [Character Map](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CharacterMap) application, and then you can copy and paste it into your diagram, or drag it in.

Comment: doesn't work. See comment above.

Comment: @user10853 have you tried dragging it to the place where you want it?

Comment: Yes & also tried GIMP.

Comment: I can paste (even non-Latin) characters into text areas in GIMP from the clip board with Ctrl+V just fine. Can you paste any text into GIMP or Dia at all? The only reason I can think of is that the selected font doesn't have the necessary glyphs but it should still show a � (the Unicode *replacement character*) in that case. To check that you can select a font that definitely has those glyphs like "Sans".

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks. No I wasn't pasting in a text area. I just tried it & it works in GIMP but not in Dia. With Sans it also works in Dia. Thanks.